# Questions about a median of a random variable

Tags: probability, analysis

A median of a random variable is defined as any $m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$P(X \le m) \ge 1/2$ and $P(X \ge m) \ge 1/2$.

(1) I am confused about the definition of the median. Is this a contradiction? Because
$$
1-P(X\le m)=P(X>m)\le 1/2...
$$
which contradicts with $P(X\ge m )\ge 1/2$.
Moreover, $P(X \le m)+P(X \ge m) \ge 1/2+1/2=1$...

(2) Also, can we give an example about the median is not unique?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with claiming that $P(X > m) \le 1/2$ or $P(X \le m) + P(X \ge m) \ge 1$. It does not rule out the case of equality after all...

Comment: There is no contradiction. For non-uniqueness, consider $P[X=0] = P[X=1] = 0.5$. Then, any $0<m<1$ is a median of $X$.

Comment: But we have $P(X>m)\le 1/2$ and $P(X\ge m)\ge 1/2$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have
   $$
   \Pr\left[X \geq m\right]
   = \Pr\left[X > m\right] + \Pr\left[X = m\right] 
   $$
   so $\Pr\left[X > m\right] \leq \frac{1}{2}$ does not contradict $\Pr\left[X \geq m\right] \geq \frac{1}{2}$ : for instance, you could have $\Pr\left[X = m\right]>0$, or if $\Pr\left[X = m\right] =0$ you could still have $\Pr\left[X > m\right]=\Pr\left[X \geq m\right]=\frac{1}{2}$.
2. Consider the case where $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$. Then any $m\in[1,2]$ is a median.